# Kinect For XBOX360 and hand tracking

Tags: kinect

I have a question about Kinect Xbox360: it can track the hand movement and fingers? I am searching on the web and I dont found any interesting about this. Another camera that I am thinking to use is the Asus Movement Sensor, but I dont know if this is better than Kinect (more options, I know that both uses OpenNI) or if both are the same.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I would see these links:

1. [Finger tracking in Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784343/finger-tracking-in-kinect)
2. http://www.kinecthacks.com/kinect-hand-tracking-gesture-experiment/
3. http://makematics.com/code/FingerTracker/
4. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c128197f-6925-49c6-bedc-d7692d03c0a9/fingers-tracking-using-kinect
5. http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Finger-Tracking-with-Kinect-SDK-and-the-Kinect-for-XBox-360-Device

These should get you started and give you many options. You can use the SDK or OpenNI, however my personal preference is the SDK, OpenNI or OpenKinect may be better in this case, expecially because of the FingerTracker API (3). Although the sdk has source code for finger tracking with an xbox kinect (5).